# Python comments: # vs. strings

Tags: python

Regarding the "standard" way to put comments inside Python source code:

```
def func():
    "Func doc"
    ... <code>
    'TODO: fix this'
    #badFunc()
    ... <more code>

def func():
    "Func doc"
    ... <code>
    #TODO: fix this
    #badFunc()
    ... <more code>
```

I prefer to write general comments as strings instead of prefixing #'s.
The official Python style guide doesn't mention using strings as comments (If I didn't miss it while reading it).

I like it that way mainly because I think the `#` character looks ugly with comment blocks. As far as I know these strings don't do anything.

Are there disadvantages in doing this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Don't misuse strings (no-op statements) as comments. Docstrings, e.g. the first string in a module, class or function, are special and definitely recommended.

Note that **docstrings are documentation**, and documentation and comments are two different things!

- Documentation is important to understand *what* the code does.
- Comments explain *how* the code does it.

Documentation is read by people who *use* your code, comments by people who want to *understand* your code, e.g. to maintain it.

Using strings for commentation has the following (potential) disadvantages:

- It confuses people who don't know that the string does nothing.
- Comments and string literals are highlighted differently in code editors, so your style may make your code harder to read.
- It might affect performance and/or memory usage (if the strings are not removed during bytecode compilation, removing comments is done on the scanner level so it's definitively cheaper)

Most important for Python programmers: It is not pythonic:

> There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it.

Stick to the standards, use comments.

Comment: For the record, it doesn't look like it will affect performance.  Looking at dis.dis output, or running strings on a compiled module shows no trace of the strings, so it looks like they're optimised away during compilation.  (The other reasons are more than sufficient however)

Answer (score 6):

I think that only the first string literal in a definition (or class) is "special", i.e. gets stored by the interpreter into the defined object's (or class') [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Any other string literals you place in the code will, at the worst, mean the interpreter will build the string value at run-time, and then just throw it away. This means that doing "comments" by littering the code with string constants might cost, performance-wise.

Of course, I have not benchmarked this, and also don't know the Python interpreter well enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 6):

The disadvantage, of course, is that someone else reading it will find that the code strings and comment strings are interleaved, which could be confusing.