# Python3.12 SyntaxWarning on triplequoted string `\d` must be `\\d`

Tags: python, warnings, quoting, python-3.12

After updating to Python 3.12, I get warnings about
invalid escape sequence on some triple-quotes comments.

Is this a new restriction? I have the habit of documenting  code using triple-quoted string, but this has never been a problem prior to Python 3.12.

```
python3 --version
Python 3.12.0
$ ./some_script.py
/some_script.py:123: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
  """
```

I tried replacing all lines with `\d`:

`20230808122708.445|INFO|C:\dist\work\trk-fullstack-test\namespaces.py`

with `\\d`:

`20230808122708.445|INFO|C:\\dist\work\trk-fullstack-test\namespaces.py`

The warning disappears.

Suppressing the warning do not seem to work:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=SyntaxWarning)
```

Any pointers on how to do this correctly? I hope I do not have to escape all Windows paths documented in triplequotes in our code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using invalid escape sequences in string literals  has been [deprecated since Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.6.html#deprecated-python-behavior). Since then, attempting to use an invalid escape sequence has emitted a [`DeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#DeprecationWarning). This often goes  unnoticed if you never run Python with [warnings enabled](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W). `DeprecationWarnings` are silenced by default.

Python 3.12 [upgraded the `DeprecationWarning` to a `SyntaxWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#other-language-changes). `SyntaxWarning`s are emitted by the compiler when the code is parsed, not when it's being run, so they cannot be ignored using a runtime warning filter. Unlike `DeprecationWarnings`, `SyntaxWarnings` are displayed by default, which is why you're seeing it now. This increase in visibility was intentional. In a future version of Python, using invalid escape sequence in string literals is planned to eventually become a hard `SyntaxError`.

The obvious solution would be to use [comments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#comments) for comments instead of string literals. Unlike string literals, comments aren't required to be syntactically valid. See the discussion in [Python comments: # vs. strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/708649/11082165) for more on why using string literals for comments is not a recommended practice.

To address this warning in general, you can make the string literal a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/11082165) `r"..."`. Raw string literals do not process escape sequences. For example, `r"\n"` is treated simply as the characters `\` and `n` and not as a newline escape sequence.

Comment: It would appear no longer valid then to put raw-string regular expressions into docstrings, which is a bummer. For sure I can replace `re.compile(r"\d+")` with `re.compile("\\d+")` but certainly the problem isn't so much for trivial cases.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang I'm not fully sure what you mean. If you're worried escape sequences being expanded inside a docstring, you can use a raw string literal for the docstring.